# Query Execution with multiple joins is taking more time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

We are trying to execute the query in the Oracle db. It is taking 5 sec in execution. All the columns are indexed.

```
select
       count(*)
from
    ehub_mbr_sds.ehub_sds_mbr a  
 join
    ehub_mbr_sds.ehub_sds_mbr_cntrct b 
        on a.ehub_mbr_id = b.ehub_mbr_id  
 join
    ehub_mbr_sds.ehub_sds_cntrct d 
        on b.cntrct_id = d.cntrct_id  
 JOIN
    EHUB_MBR_SDS.EHUB_SDS_CVRG c 
        ON b.EHUB_MBR_CNTRCT_ID= c.EHUB_MBR_CNTRCT_ID   
 JOIN
    EHUB_MBR_SDS.EHUB_SDS_ELGBLTY f 
        ON f.PROD_CD= c.PROD_CD  
 JOIN
    ehub_mbr_sds.ehub_sds_grp e 
        on d.ehub_grp_id = e.ehub_grp_id   
where
    a.sor_cd ='****' 
    AND e.GRP_ID='****' --need indexes for  GRPID
    AND c.sub_grp_id='*****'  
    and f.plan_type_cd in('***') 
    and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > c.cvrg_efctv_dt 
    and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > c.cvrg_trmntn_dt 
order by
    b.hcid;
```

Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: how much data on average have those tables ? how much data you are selecting maybe a full table scan needed, how is the data is being distributed , what I can suggest to run a tunning advisor (note sure if liscence needed )

Comment: `select count(*)` combined with `order by` makes no sense

Comment: Show the execution plan and the indexes that you have.

Comment: 5.5 k count is getting returned

Comment: removed order by performance is still not good

Answer (score 0):

Post an explain plan. In the meantime, re-try the query using parallelism with a hint in front of your select. I. E.

```
select /*+parallel*/...
```

Ensure that the parallelism is working by grabbing the explain plan with and without the hint. (It's possible your server isn't configured for parallel execution)

Comment: I'd be cautious using parallelism to speed up a 5 second query.  Parallel queries have a lot of overhead for process startup, shutdown, and coordination, as well as increased parse time for dynamic sampling.  It might be possible to improve the run-time on a 5 second query, but would it be worth it if the total database time was significantly increased?  Oracle parallelism is great but I think the OP should try to make the query work smarter before trying to make it work harder.

Comment: Added the explain plan, can you help in analyzing it

Comment: Mentions dynamic sampling... "It is typically used to compensate for missing or insufficient statistics that would otherwise lead to a very bad plan. For the case where one or more of the tables in the query does not have statistics, DS is used by the optimizer to gather basic statistics on these tables before optimizing the statement." Maybe gather some stats?

Comment: added dynamic statics = 4, hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("C"."CVRG_TRMNTN_DT"))<SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)))
   - 4 Sql Plan Directives used for this statement
   - Degree of Parallelism is 4 because of hint
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=4)
   - this is an adaptive plan
  14 - filter(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("C"."CVRG_EFCTV_DT"))<SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)) AND 
  19 - access("C"."SUB_GRP_ID"='****')
  21 - access("B"."EHUB_MBR_CNTRCT_ID"="C"."EHUB_MBR_CNTRCT_ID")
  22 - filter("D"."EHUB_GRP_ID" IS NOT NULL)
  23 - access("B"."CNTRCT_ID"="D"."****")
  24 - filter("E"."GRP_ID"='****')
  25 - access("E"."EHUB_GRP_ID"="D"."*****")
  26 - filter("A"."SOR_CD"='***')
  27 - access("A"."EHUB_MBR_ID"="B"."*****")
  28 - access("F"."PROD_CD"="C"."*****")
  29 - filter("F"."PLAN_TYPE_CD"='****')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note
Plan hash value: 2232660988
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                 |                        |     1 |   161 |  2775   (1)| 00:00:01 |        |      |            |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                                  |                        |     1 |   161 |            |          |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                                 |                        |       |       |            |          |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                           | :TQ10003               |     1 |   161 |            |          |  Q1,03 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE                               |                        |     1 |   161 |            |          |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                                |                        |     1 |   161 |  2775   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                               |                        |    12 |   161 |  2775   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                              |                        |     1 |   147 |  2771   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                             |                        |     1 |   128 |  2771   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                            |                        |     1 |   108 |  2770   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                           |                        |     1 |    92 |  2770   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  11 |            BUFFER SORT                           |                        |       |       |            |          |  Q1,03 | PCWC |            |
|  12 |             PX RECEIVE                           |                        |       |       |            |          |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|  13 |              PX SEND HASH                        | :TQ10001               |       |       |            |          |  Q1,01 | P->P | HASH       |
|  15 |                BUFFER SORT                       |                        |       |       |            |          |  Q1,01 | PCWC |            |
|  16 |                 PX RECEIVE                       |                        |  3845 |       |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|  17 |                  PX SEND HASH (BLOCK ADDRESS)    | :TQ10000               |  3845 |       |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | S->P | HASH (BLOCK|
|  18 |                   PX SELECTOR                    |                        |       |       |            |          |  Q1,00 | SCWC |            |
|  20 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID           | EHUB_SDS_MBR_CNTRCT    |     1 |    39 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
| Id  | Operation                                        | Name                   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
|* 14 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| EHUB_SDS_CVRG          |     1 |    53 |  2769   (1)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,01 | PCWP |            |
|* 19 |                    INDEX RANGE SCAN              | IX4_EHUB_SDS_CVRG      |  3845 |       |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,00 | SCWP |            |
|* 21 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                    | PK_EHUB_SDS_MBR_CNTRCT |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 22 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | EHUB_SDS_CNTRCT        |     1 |    16 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 23 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | PK_EHUB_SDS_CNTRCT     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 24 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID             | EHUB_SDS_GRP           |     1 |    20 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 25 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                      | PK_EHUB_SDS_GRP        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 26 |         TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | EHUB_SDS_MBR           |     1 |    19 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 27 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | PK_EHUB_SDS_MBR        |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 28 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                          | IX3_EHUB_SDS_ELGBLTY   |    12 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
|* 29 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                | EHUB_SDS_ELGBLTY       |   990 | 13860 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |  Q1,03 | PCWP |            |
```